# How can I change the property of javascript classes?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I create two classes, that have the method to attack other class.Attacking class inflict damage to defending class, that is take damage property from attacking class and subtract its number from hp property of other class. Chance to inflict damage is 100% - (property strength + agility of defending class). The problem conclude,attack method in class, which must changes hp property of other class, doesn't change it.

```
class Fighter {
    Wins = 0;
    Losess = 0;
    constructor (obj) {
        this.name = obj.name;
        this.damage = obj.damage;
        this.hp = obj.hp;
        this.strength = obj.strength;
        this.agility = obj.agility;
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    getDamage() {
        return this.damage;
    }
    getStrength() {
        return this.strength;
    }  
    getAgility() {
        return this.agility
    }  
    getHealth() {
        return this.hp;
    }    
    attack(obj) {
        let rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
        if(rand < (obj.strength + obj.agility)) {
            console.log(`${this.name} make ${this.damage} damage to ${obj.name}`);
            obj.hp - this.damage;
        } else {
            console.log(`${this.name} attack missed`)
        }
    }
}

const myFighter = new Fighter({name: "Maximus", damage: 25, hp: 100, strength: 30, agility: 25});
const myFighter2 = new Fighter({name: "Comodus", damage: 20, hp: 100, strength: 15, agility: 20});

console.log(myFighter2.getHealth());

myFighter.attack(myFighter2);

console.log(myFighter2.getHealth());
```

Comment: Btw, in idiomatic JavaScript you don't write getter methods. You just access the properties directly. Should the need for a getter arise, you just change the data property to a getter one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `obj.hp - this.damage` you're calculating the new value but you're not storing the value anywhere. To update the value of `obj.hp` you should write this: `obj.hp = obj.hp - this.damage`. In this way, the result (`obj.hp - this.damage`) is stored as new value of `obj.hp`.

P.S. There is a short cut in js to write the this operation: `obj.hp -= this.damage`